# GraphQL server not starting

Tags: typescript, graphql

I am new to GraphQL and was learning it. I am going through the [getting started document](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/getting-started#step-7-start-the-server) on Apollo's website.
I followed the same instructions but when it comes to running the server, I can't seem to do it.

Error I receive:

```
Error: Cannot find module '...graphql-fcc-example\dist\index.js'
```

I have a index.ts and schema.ts inside src folder.

index.ts

```
// For these to work, type="module"
import { ApolloServer } from '@apollo/server'; // to connect with the server
import { startStandaloneServer } from '@apollo/server/standalone'; // to start
import { typeDefs } from './schema';
import db from '../database/_db'; 

const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        games() {
            return db.games;
        },
        reviews() {
            return db.reviews;
        },
        authors() {
            return db.authors;
        }
    }
}

const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs, resolvers
})

const { url } = await startStandaloneServer(server, {listen: {port: 4000 }});

console.log("server ready at port", 4000);
```

schema.ts

```
export const typeDefs = `#graphql
type Game {
    id: ID!,
    title: String!,
    platform: [String!]!
}

type Review {
    id: ID!,
    rating: Int!,
    content: String!
}

type Author {
    id: ID!,
    name: String!,
    verified: Boolean!
}

type Query {
    games: [Game]
    authors: [Author]
    reviews: [Review]
}
`
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "graphql-fcc-example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "compile": "tsc",
    "start": "npm run compile && node ./dist/index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/server": "^4.10.0",
    "graphql": "^16.8.1",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.11.16",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  },
  "description": ""
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "name": "graphql-fcc-example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "compile": "tsc",
    "start": "npm run compile && node ./dist/index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/server": "^4.10.0",
    "graphql": "^16.8.1",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.11.16",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  },
  "description": ""
}
```

Solutions I have tried

- npm run install to check if typescript code is getting compiled successfully and it is.
- check the folder structure
- npm install to re-download the dependencies
- My VSCode also shows me no error in the written code

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a typescript configuration problem. Your `npm start` is looking to run the compiled javascript file at `./dist/index.js` but there's nothing there. Check your tsconfig file to see where ts is putting the compiled code.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is facing the same issue with their code, the thing that solved this problem was changing the name of imported files from `schema` to `schema.js` and same with from `_db` to `_db.js`. Adding the extension of the file to the import statements solved the problem for me.